# Ending process when negative height is entered

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, sentinel

im having trouble finishing off this program, we are supposed to write a program to draw a triangle using "*", where it asks for the height and width, and we are required to have it go in a loop where it keeps asking for more heights and widths, until the user enters a negative value in the height, it is supposed to store there. Heres what i have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Rectangles {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("\n\n"
        + "Drawing Rectangles\n"
        + "------------------\n\n"); 
    while(height >= 0) {
        int height = -1, width = -1;
        System.out.print("Enter the height and width of a rectangle: ");
        height = kbd.nextInt();
        width = kbd.nextInt();
        kbd.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\n" 
            + "Here is your rectangle:");
        drawRectangle(height, width);
        System.out.print("\n\n");
    }
}

private static void drawRectangle(int height, int width) {

    for (int line = 1; line <= height; line++) {
        for (int star = 1; star <= width; star++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

So far i have this, it starts, asks for height, width then draws a triangle thats it. any ideas how i could make it go in a loop to ask for more and stop only when the user enters a negative value in the height? NO IF STATEMENTS ALLOWED. Thanks in advance

Comment: The best way to do this involves an `if` statement.  You might want to consider relaxing your last condition, if you don't want to end up with an inferior solution.

Comment: You're close. Your `while(height > 0)` should be around the portion where you're asking for the height and width in the main.

Comment: i know how to do it with an if statement, but the whole point of writing this is to do it using no if statements, only loops.

Comment: Also, is 0 a valid response? It's not negative, you may want to consider changing your condition to `while(height >= 0)`

Comment: i tried moving it over, but it is giving me errors because the height and width ints need to be initialized? but i cant set them to a certain amount since the user is supposed to do that @lolynns and yes u are right i changed it to >=

Comment: It's good practice to initialize variables to your stop condition so if the user enters something invalid, this doesn't crash the program. `int height = -1, width = -1;` would still fulfill your program requirements.

Comment: just did that, it just draws a rectangle right away with negative height and width, since they have already been set

Comment: post your code updates

Comment: just updated it

Comment: You want it to draw a rectangle every time right? So...the call to drawRectagle() should be in the while loop as well. So should your `"Enter the height and width of a rectangle: "` prompt. Also, consider your while condition. It never enters into that code with your variable instantiated outside of it.

Comment: i just updated the code again, moved it over inside the loop and still no change

Comment: The last thing you need to consider is what your while loop is testing for. Negative numbers right? So it will never be entered into with your variable declarations outside of the loop...

Comment: (also, your `"Here is your rectangle:"` output should still be above the drawRectangle() call inside the while loop)

Comment: im not sure what you mean by saying it will never be entered into with your variables outside of the loop, if youre saying move the declaration inside the loop it just gives me an error since "height" is declared after it is used, i also tried the code i updated above, no errors, but it doesnt stop when its negative

Comment: no, they shouldn't be class variables. They should either be initialized inside your loop, or get the first user values before entering into the loop. See what I did below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.print("\n\n"
    + "Drawing Rectangles\n"
    + "------------------\n\n");

int height = -1, width = -1;
System.out.print("Enter the height and width of a rectangle: ");
height = kbd.nextInt();
width = kbd.nextInt();
kbd.nextLine();
while(height > -1) {
    System.out.println("\n" + "Here is your rectangle:");
    drawRectangle(height, width);
    System.out.print("\n\n");

    System.out.print("Enter the height and width of a rectangle: ");
    height = kbd.nextInt();
    width = kbd.nextInt();
    kbd.nextLine();
}


}

private static void drawRectangle(int height, int width) {

for (int line = 1; line <= height; line++) {
    for (int star = 1; star <= width; star++) {
        System.out.print("*");

    }

    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this works perfectly, still a little confused as to why the other way wouldnt work, im sure i can figure that out though! Thanks again really appreciate it